# C++ GCC 4.3.2 error on vector of char-array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, destructor

It is similar in problem to this bug

[Question about storing array in a std::vector in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468058/question-about-storing-array-in-a-stdvector-in-c)

but for a different reason (see below).

For the following sample program in C++:

```
#include <vector>

int main(int c_, char ** v_)
{
        const int LENGTH = 100;

        std::vector<char[LENGTH]> ca_vector;

        return 0;

}
```

GCC 4.2.3 compiles cleanly.
GCC 4.3.2 emits the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_construct.h: In function ‘void std::_Destroy(_Tp*) [with _Tp = char [100]]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_construct.h:103:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = char (*)[100]]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_construct.h:128:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator&) [with _ForwardIterator = char (*)[100], _Tp = char [100]]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:300:   instantiated from ‘std::vector::~vector() [with _Tp = char [100], _Alloc = std::allocator]’
test.cpp:7:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_construct.h:88: error: request for member ‘~char [100]’ in ‘* __pointer’, which is of non-class type ‘char [100]’
```

The reason apparently is this bit in

```
include/g++-v4/bits/stl_construct.h
```

```
  template
    inline void
    _Destroy(_Tp* __pointer)
    { __pointer->~_Tp(); }
```

which is called, I think, due to incorrect array-to-pointer-decay.

My question is:
**Is there anything in language standard preventing storage of arrays in std::vector?** Or is it just a bug in that special GCC version?

I do believe that this should compile (i.e. 4.2.3 is correct).

Thanks 
martin

Comment: Any reason you're not using std::string?

Comment: Are you saying that your code compiled and executed correcly in GCC 4.2.3?

Comment: It still compiles on that system, yes. And it seems to work.

Comment: @kmarsh: I have already replaced it with std::string (would have from the beginning); I inherited that piece of code, but I have to admit, I wouldn't have known it was illegal (I hardly ever use raw arrays these days); after the answers, it seems quite logical now that it should be forbidden. And I don't like to think about why it worked so far and whether it really did...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is something in the standard stopping using arrays Using [Draft C++98 Standard](ftp://ftp.research.att.com/pub/c++std/WP/CD2/)

> Section 23 Containers
>
> The type of objects stored in these components must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible
> types (20.1.3), and the additional requirements of Assignabletypes.

where components are various containers

20.1.3 includes the requirement that the type has to have a destructor.

I think of it as a vector has to copy allocate and delete elements. How does C++ know to copy or delete a char[] ?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, good job. Should have found it myself, but was too block-headed. 
Other answers are correct, too, I am marking this, since it was the fastest.
regards martin

Comment: I'm sure you're misreading it. `std::vector<int>` is very legal even though int has no destructor either.

Comment: You can do x = new int(5): delete x; - but to delete an array you need delete []

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this is not allowed, just like it wasn't allowed in the question you linked to (and I don't see how the "reason is different"). It's not a "bug" in either of the two questions. Or at least, not a bug in the compiler. Just in your code. ;)

You can't store an array in a vector, because a vector requires its elements to be copy-constructible and assignable.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution to do this is:

```
std::vector<boost::array<LENGTH> > ca_vector;
```

This way you don't have to bother with the array/pointer story.
Whether you really want this, is another question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. In fact in my concrete case vector<string> is the (probably intended) solution to the problem in the (legacy) source code I am reviewing (so it's not raw bytes or anything but just strings). I am not at all sure why there even is a char[]-array and not a string, when there is already a vector; I can only imagine some obscure (and probably misguided) optimization considerations on part of the original author...

Comment: If it is a string, use a string.  I used my construction as a temporary solution to store byte-based messages in an stl-container.

Comment: or std::vector<std::tr1::array<LENGTH> > ca_vector;

Answer (score -1):

Please let me know  mind of this code. You already know, vector is also some kind of an array and you dont have to give initial size.

```
1D vector  ->  std::vector<char*> ca_vector;
2D vector  ->  std::vector<char*,char*> ca_vector;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I am aware that the vector can be used as an array, as you have correctly pointed out. 
What I wanted to know is if the above code is legal in the sense of the standard. I could have put a vector of strings vector<string> there but as Mark has written, an basic C/C++ array does not fulfill the the requirements on container elements.

Comment: @Aykut: std::vector<char*,char*> doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The second template argument to vector is not the type of the second dimension (vectors only have one dimension). The second argument is the allocate (defaulting to the standard allocator).

Comment: a 2D vector would look something like: std::vector<std::vector<char*> >