# Vector of multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

Is there any way to make vectors of multidimensional arrays? im trying to make a vector with 2 dimensional integer arrays as its elements, but `vector<int[4][4]>` is not working. What is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: Can't your do a class containing a `int[4][4]` ? Then a `std::vector` of your class ...

Comment: If what you really want is a vector of matrices, or a 3-dimensional vector, I can recommend Armadillo: http://arma.sf.net

Answer (score 3):

You can't have vectors of arrays at all. Standard container element types must be *copyable*, and arrays are not copyable.

However, you can have a vector of vectors, like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >
```

Play with this.

Or, to stick with arrays:

```
std::vector<boost::array<int, N> >
```

Or, if you have C++0x:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, N> >
```

`{boost,std}::array` is an object wrapper around automatic-storage-duration arrays, so it's pretty close to what you were originally attempting.

Comment: really boost or c++0x to implement int[4][4] ? Kind of a big tools to implement something quite basic ...

Comment: @vrince: Write your own `struct T { int ar[4][4]; };` if it bothers you. And that the relevant headers in Boost or C++0x are "big tools" is a complete myth; they are in fact very lightweight. (It _is_ a bit of a shame that native arrays aren't copyable in the first place... blame C for that.)

Comment: "big tools" is not the appropriate expression your right, I was trying to use a French expression that literary says "killing a fly with a hammer" ... obviously I failed :). I am just afraid needhelps will just miss the `copyable` concept using those libs.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with built in multidimensional arrays.

But you could use [Boost multi-dimensional arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468058/question-about-storing-array-in-a-stdvector-in-c/1468304#1468304) has a good explanation why it's not doable. Basically, the type int[4][4] is not assignable.

Answer (score 0):

As @vrince suggested in the comment, you can have a class/struct encapsulating `int[4][4]`:

```
struct My2DArray {
  int a[4][4];
};
```

And declare `vector` for above:

```
vector<My2DArray> obj;
```

For ease you can define various `operator`s and `public` methods (say like copy constructor, assignment operator etc.) to deal with it.